# api level not listed in Android Studio

Tags: android

my app is live on Google Play. it is presently api 23 or Android 6.0. Got a notice from Google that the app has to be api 26 by November 1st. not sure if this is for updates, or the app currently there. the problem with changing the api higher is less people may download it getting the device not compatible message. I use Android Studio to compile my app. In project structure my 23 is listed. it then jumps to api 28. api 26 is not offered. I use AS version 3.1. How may I upgrade the api to 26 in AS? thanks. this is a simple app that works on Android 4.4 or api 16.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the minSdk version to 26, just your target and compile versions.

And you shouldn't only set them to 26. You should set them to 28.

Note: if your minSdk is currently below 14, you will need to set it to 14 or higher. This is a limitation introduced in 26.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I installed the 26 sdk option in AS. The problem is the higher the api invokes the inverse relation: higher api, less people that may download it. when must I change to sdk?

Comment: @StevePaul by the end of 2018. At that point, every app will be targeting 26, with a minimum of 14 or higher

Comment: @StevePaul Not for targetSDK.  target only effects the version of the tools you use to compile with, and the behavior of a few function calls on higher level OSes.  You can still keep the minimum very low.

Comment: I now realize this. In AS through the project structure I set target to 26 and min sdk to 16 or Android 4.4. thnanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong understanding of `targetSdkVersion`. Increasing `targetSdkVersion` doesn't reduce the number of people who can download your apps. It is the `minSdkVersion` that effects your apps reach. 
Regarding google's requirement you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk). New apps need to target at least api 26 from August 1, 2018 and app updates need to target at least api 26 from November 1, 2018.

Comment: I now realize this. In AS through the project structure I set target to 26 and min sdk to 16 or Android 4.4. thnanks for the reply